# secure ftp with indy / delphi -> file upload & download

Tags: delphi

I need to upload files to a secure ftp share,  I only know the config data from FILE ZILLA Ftp client. Protocoll is SSH , secure FTP

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
 - <FileZilla3>
 - <Servers>
 - <Server>
 <Host>example.com</Host> 
 <Port>22</Port> 
 <Protocol>1</Protocol> 
 <Type>0</Type> 
 <User>Username-FTP</User> 
 <Pass>*************/Pass> 
 <Logontype>1</Logontype> 
 <TimezoneOffset>0</TimezoneOffset> 
 <PasvMode>MODE_DEFAULT</PasvMode> 
 <MaximumMultipleConnections>0</MaximumMultipleConnections> 
 <EncodingType>Auto</EncodingType> 
 <BypassProxy>0</BypassProxy> 
 <Name>Ftp_sharename</Name> 
 <Comments /> 
 <LocalDir /> 
 <RemoteDir>8 0 15 dsd_dir</RemoteDir> 
 <SyncBrowsing>0</SyncBrowsing> 
  Ftp_server_name
   </Server>
   </Servers>
 </FileZilla3>
```

with code like

```
 procedure TForm1.btnConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
 begin
  if IdFTP1.Connected then
  begin
  IdFtp1.Disconnect;
  btnConnect.Caption := 'Verbinden';
  ListBox1.Clear;
 end
 else begin
 IdFTP1.Host := edHost.Text;
 IdFtp1.Username := edUser.Text;
 IdFtp1.Password := edPassword.Text;
 IdFtp1.Port := StrToINt(edport.Text);
 IdFtp1.Connect;
 end;
end;
```

using INDY 10  - IdFTP1: TIdFTP; not much luck. Did not find any better compenent with my Delphi.

Answer (score 3):

**SFTP** (FTP over SSH) is different than **FTPS** (FTP over SSL/TLS).  At this time, Indy does not support SSH at all.  `TIdFTP` does support FTPS, however.

Comment: OK, this means FILEZILLA is using SSH, I can't write an FTP client using INDY :-(